# How can I change fieldsets order?

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

I have a form schema which inherits from another form schema. Both have [fieldsets](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/fieldsets.html). However, the fieldsets are put in the order they are created. So the fieldset described in the last schema will be the last one. I would like it to be the first. Is there a way to do that ?

Example:

```py
from plone.supermodel import model
from zope import schema

class FormSchema(model.Schema):
     model.fieldset(
          'test',
          label='Test',
          fields=['field1']
     )
     field1 = schema.Text(title=u'test')


class FormSchema2(FormSchema):
     # Is last but I would like to place it first
     model.fieldset(
          'test2',
          label='Test2',
          fields=['field2']
     )
     field2 = schema.Text(title=u'test2')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but you could try declaring each fieldset in its own class, and mix them in a third one in the right order. Eg: `class FormSchemaFinal(FormSchemaFieldset2,FormSchemaFieldset1):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, I am afraid. The schema fieldsets are *always* merged in reverse interface resolution order; base before derived interface. Declaring the fieldset *again* on the `FormSchema2` schema will only result in the fieldset being listed twice.

If you *have* to control fieldset order, don't derive from the base schema but re-declare it.

Comment: This answer, of course, is not 100% factually correct. You can whack the crap out of zope interfaces by manually manipulating their internals. But you don't want to do this :)

Comment: @Mikko: you can set the tagged values with the `setTaggedValue()` method on the base schema. Or monkeypatch `plone.supermodel` or `plone.autoform`. But that'd either break the base schema or requires intimate knowledge of the two frameworks and would be extremely fragile.